# Assigning status to books in library program

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm really new at java so sorry for the inconsistencies/confusion in my code.

Im creating a simple library program and one of the requirements are to display all the books in the library and their status(in or out)

for example:

> Great Expectations: IN
>
> Kite Runner: OUT
>
> Wuthering Heights: OUT

however if i just check one book out, it changes ALL the book status' to "out" instead of just one of them. so for example i keep on getting:

> Great Expectations: OUT
>
> Kite Runner: OUT
>
> Wuthering Heights: OUT

In my book class I have the status setters/getters like so and also an ArrayList BookList to hold all the library books.

```java
static ArrayList <String> BookList = new ArrayList <String> ();

public static String getStatus(String book)
    {
        return status; 
    }

  public static void setStatus(String newStatus)    
    {
        status = newStatus; 
    }
```

And here is the methods in the patron class to check out books.

```java
public static void CheckOutBook() 
{
      Scanner inputread = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter full patron name: ");
      String borrower = inputread.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter book title to check out: ");
      String bookCheckOut = inputread.nextLine();

      if (Book.BookList.contains(bookCheckOut)) 
      {
        Book.BookList.remove(bookCheckOut);
        Book.setStatus("OUT");                   //?? doesnt work ??
        int bookIndex = Book.getIndexNumber(bookCheckOut);
        Book.setTrue(Book.BookList.get(bookIndex));
        Book.setBook(Book.BookList.get(bookIndex));
        Book.setBorrower(borrower);
        Book.setBook(bookCheckOut);
        System.out.println("----------" + bookCheckOut + " has been checked out!----------");

      }
}
```

How can I make it so only the specified book in the array list changes its status? I've tried to create different methods but that doesnt seem to work either:

```java
Book.setTrue(bookCheckOut);              //true if book checked out
Book.BookList.get(indexNum).setTrue(bookCheckOut);
Book.setTrue(Book.BookList.get(i));

//here are some of the other attemps ive tried but they still dont change anything :(
```

Book Class:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Book implements BookInterface {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  static ArrayList < String > UserList = new ArrayList < String > ();
  static ArrayList < String > BookList = new ArrayList < String > (); //display just titles// use when checking out books
  static ArrayList < String > OrigBookList = new ArrayList < String > (); //keep track of all titles ever entered

  public static String title;
  public String author;
  public static String book;
  public boolean checkIn;

  public static String status;
  public static String borrower;


  public Book(String t, String a) {
    title = t;
    author = a;
  }


  //constructor create new book
  public Book(String newTitle) {
    title = newTitle;
  }


  public String toString() {
    return title + " " + author;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
  }

  public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
  }

   public static String getStatus(String book) {
    return status;
  }

  public static void setStatus(String newStatus) 
    {
      status = newStatus;


  /**public static void setStatus(String newStatus)
    {
        status = newStatus; 
    }**/

  public static void setTrue(String bookCheckOut) {
    //status = true; 
  }

  public static void setFalse(String bookCheckIn) {
    //status = false; 
  }

  public static void setBorrower(String newBorrower) {
    borrower = newBorrower;
  }

  public static String getBorrower(String checkPatron) {
    return borrower;
  }

  public static String getBook(String checkPatron) {
    return book;
  }

  public static void setBook(String newBook) {
    book = newBook;
  }

  public static void addBook() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inputread = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter book title: ");

    String title1 = inputread.nextLine();

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter book author: ");
    String author1 = inputread.next();

    Book fullBook = new Book(title1, author1); //create constructor w/ title & author
    Book book1 = new Book(title1); //constructor w/ just title to be used to display all books
    BookList.add(title1);
    OrigBookList.add(title1);
    //setStatus("IN");  //false = checked in 
    setFalse(title1);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("-----" + title1 + " is now in the library!-----");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
  }

  public static void editBook() {
    Scanner inputread = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter original book title: ");
    String origTitle = inputread.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter edited book title: ");
    String editedTitle = inputread.nextLine();
    Collections.replaceAll(Book.UserList, origTitle, editedTitle);
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(origTitle + " has been changed to " + editedTitle + "!");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");

  }


  //print out list of books & if checked in or out
  public static void libraryInventory() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= OrigBookList.size() - 1; i++) {
      //Book Title: checked in/out
      System.out.println(OrigBookList.get(i) + ":" + getStatus(OrigBookList.get(i)));
    }
  }

  //method to go through BookList array and get index number for specifed 
  //book user has entered to check in/out 
  public static int getIndexNumber(String bookCheckOut) {
    int bookIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= BookList.size() - 1; i++) {
      if (BookList.get(i).equals(bookCheckOut)) {
        bookIndex = i;
      }

    }
    return bookIndex;

  }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code in the `Book` class?

Comment: hi! i just posted my Book class, sorry if its a bit messy!

Comment: Most of your fields are static.  So, that means that there's only one value for that field shared across all instances.  **Do not use static fields or methods.  Create instances.**

Answer (score 1):

For your getStatus method you are using a static variable, this means that it will be the same across alll Book instances, you don't want that, just remove all the static from the variables and methods in Book and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In order to model your "library", you need to have *instances* of Books. Think of your Book class as a blueprint that defines what a book is. You then need to use this blueprint to create actual Book objects.

Keeping it simple, here is an example of a Book class. It defines a Book that has a title and a checked out status.

```
public class Book {
  private String title;
  private boolean isCheckedOut;
  public Book(String title, boolean isCheckedOut) {
    this.title = title;
    this.isCheckedOut = isCheckdOut;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }
  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }
  public void setCheckedOut(boolean isCheckedOut) {
    this.isCheckedOut = isCheckedOut;
  }
  public boolan isCheckedOut() {
    return isCheckedOut;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return title + ": " + (isCheckedOut ? "OUT" : "IN");
  }
}
```

You would create specific books like this:

```
Book greatExpectations = new Book("Great Expectations", false);
```

This creates a new book with the title "Great Expectations", which is not checked out. `System.out.println(greatExpectations)` would print `Great Expectations: OUT`.

So to set up your "library", let's create a collection of books and add them to a `List`:

```
List<Book> library = new ArrayList<>();
library.add(new Book("Great Expectations", false));
library.add(new Book("Moby Dick", false));
library.add(new Book("Catch-22", false));
library.add(new Book("The Great Gatsby", false));
```

Now if I want to mark *Catch-22* as being checked out, all I need to do is loop through the list, find the book I'm looking for, and change its checked out state:

```
for(Book book : library) {
  if("Catch-22".equals(book.getTitle()) {
    book.setCheckedOut(true);
    break; // found the book, break out of the loop
  }
}
```

If I now print out the contents of `library`, I'll see that only *Catch-22* is marked as being checked out:

```
System.out.println(library);

// prints:
// [Great Expectations: IN, Moby Dick: IN, Catch-22: OUT, The Great Gatsby: IN]
```

---

Your implementation is using static methods. A static method doesn't set the value of a particular instance, but rather a value that is shared across all instances.

So in terms of the Book class, a static method isn't setting a property for a particular book, but rather *all* books. That's why when you tried to set a book as being checked out, it updated *all* the books as being checked out.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you! i had a feeling it had something to do with all my static methods but i wasn't too sure. Anyways, i removed everything static in my Book class and also Patron class however when i try to set the status, "Book.setStatus("OUT"); in the Patron class it gives me an error saying "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setStatus(String)" but i removed everything static from both Book and Patron so I'm stuck on why I'm still getting this message. Thanks again!

Comment: @kayylai You need to call `setStatus` against an *instance* of Book. You're trying to call it against the Book class in general, which would require a static method. You need to first get the book that you want to modify, then call `setStatus` against it -- eg. `Book catch22 = new Book("Catch-22"); catch22.setStatus("OUT");`.